# Skip all type of characters matlab while using fscanf or sscanf

Tags: matlab, scanf

I need to read a text that has mix of numerical values and characters. Here is an example:

```
% Loc  : LAT  = -19.6423        LON = -70.817       DEP = 21.5451196625
```

I only need to read numerical fields.

Typically I used this:

```
x = fgetl(fid);

out = sscanf(x,'%% Loc  : LAT  = %f LON = %f DEP = %f\n');
```

It works but the problem is that not all the files have fixed format and sometimes letters are written in upper or lower cases. In such cases what I did does not work.

I tried skipping all characters using

```
out = sscanf(x,'%[a-zA-Z.=\t\b]s %f %[a-zA-Z.=\t\b]s %f %[a-zA-Z.=\t\b]s %f\n');
```

but it does not work!

Please note that file lines are not the same and I have different number of numerical field in each line of file.

Comment: Can you, please, add any other example of input file lines to allow better understanding the possible structure of the file?

Comment: Expanding on the comment by @il_raffa, the part where you say that "not all of the files have fixed format" seems especially important.

Comment: @il_raffa As you improvised an example in your proposed solution in each line of text file I may have different number of numerical values. `% Mech : STRK = 357.0  DIP = 18.0  RAKE = 113.582236842 Htop = 0.68644 km `

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution even if it is for sure not "elegant", nevertheless seems working.

It is based on the following process:

- read the file line by line using `fgets`
- parse each string using `strtok`
- try converting each token to a numebr with `str2num`
- if it is actually a "number" `str2num` (i. e. if `str2num` does not returns an empty array) insert the number in the output matrix

The output matrix is initialized (to `NaN`) at the beginning of the script as big enough to have:

- a number of rows greater or equal to the number of rows of the input file (if it is not known in advance, a "reasonable" value should be defined)
- a number of columns greater or equal to the maximum number of numeric values that can be present in a row of the input file (if it is not known in advance, a "reasonable" value should be defined).

Once you've read all the input file, you can "clean" the the output matrix by removing the exceeding full NaN rows and columns.

In the following you can find the script, the input file I've used and the output matrix (looking at it should make more clear the reason for having initialized it to `NaN` - I hope).

Notice that the identification of the number and their extraction (using `strtok`) is based on the format of your the example row: in particular, for example, it is based on the fact that all the token of the string are separated by a  space.

This means that the code is not able to identify `=123.456` as number.

If your input file has token such as `=123.456`, the code has to be modified.

```
% Initialize rows counter
r_cnt=0;
% INitialize column counter
c_cnt=0;
% Define the number of rows of the input file (if it not known in advance,
% put a "reasonable" value) - Used to initialize the output matrix
file_rows=5;
% Define the number of numeric values to be extracted from the input file
% (if it not known in advance, put a "reasonable" value) - Used to
% initialize the output matrix
max_col=5;
% Initialize the variable holding the maximum number of column. Used to
% "clean" the output matrix
max_n_col=-1;
% Initialize the output matrix
m=nan(file_rows,max_col);
% Open the input file
fp=fopen('char_and_num.txt','rt');
% Get the first row
tline = fgets(fp);
% Loop to read line by line the input file
while ischar(tline)
   % Increment the row counter
   r_cnt=r_cnt+1;
   % Parse the line looking for numeric values
   while(true)
      [str, tline] = strtok(tline);
      if(isempty(str))
         break
      end
      % Try to conver the string into a number
      tmp_val=str2num(str);
      if(~isempty(tmp_val))
         % If the token is a number, increment the column counter and
         % insert the number in the output matrix
         c_cnt=c_cnt+1;
         m(r_cnt,c_cnt)=tmp_val;
      end
   end
   % Identify the maximum number not NaN column in the in the output matrix
   % so far
   max_n_col=max(max_n_col,c_cnt);
   % Reset the column counter before nest iteration
   c_cnt=0;
   % Read next line of the input file
   tline = fgets(fp);
end
% After having read all the input file, close it
fclose(fp)
% Clean the output matrix removing the exceeding full NaN rows and columns
m(r_cnt+1:end,:)=[];
m(:,max_n_col+1:end)=[];
m
```

**Input file**

```
% Loc  : LAT  = -19.6423        LON = -70.817                      DEP = 21.5451196625
% Loc  : xxx  = -1.234          yyy = -70.000   WIDTH = 333.369    DEP = 456.5451196625
% Loc  : zzz  = 1.23
```

**Output**

```
m =

  -19.6423  -70.8170   21.5451       NaN
   -1.2340  -70.0000  333.3690  456.5451
    1.2300       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I think this could be simpler in my case since every numerical field comes after `=` sign. Inspired by your approach I write something like this in a loop until all data is read: `fscanf(fid,'%[^=]');
fscanf(fid,'=');
fscanf(fid,'%f')` By the first line I read until the match character of `=`.

Comment: the complete code would be like: `c = 1;
while c <= 15
    fscanf(fid,'%[^=]s');
    fscanf(fid,'=');
    out(c) = fscanf(fid,'%f');
    c = c + 1;
end
fclose(fid);` In this case I know that I only have 15 numerical fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little unclear on your file format, but it seems like you could do this much easier using `textscan` instead of the lower level functions.

Something like this should work:

```
 while (~feof(fid))
      textscan(fid, '%s :'); % Read the part of the line through the colon
      data = textscan(fid, '%s = %f');
      % Do something with the data here
 end
```

The variable `fid` is an file identifier that you would have to have gotten from calling `fopen` and you'll need to call `fclose` when you're done.

I don't think this is going to exactly fix your problem, but hopefully it will get you on a track that's much shorter and cleaner.  You'll have to play with this to make sure that you actually get to the end of file, for example, and that there are not corner cases that trip up the pattern matching.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually as I commented before I found an easier solution based on two approaches. one is to read until finding the matching character of `=` and then reading `=` character and then reading  the next numerical field and store it. It would something like this: `c = 1;
NoOfNumField = 5;
out = zeros(NoOfNumField,1);
while c <= NoOfNumField
    fscanf(fid,'%[^=]s');
    fscanf(fid,'=');
    out(c) = fscanf(fid,'%f\n');
    c = c + 1;
end`

Comment: Another approach is to read until the first numerical value and then reading the numerical field. This has one step less then the previous method. Code would be like: `c = 1;
NoOfNumField = 5;
out = zeros(NoOfNumField,1);
while c <= NoOfNumField
    x = fscanf(fid,'%[^0-9-+]c');
    %fscanf(fid,'=');
    out(c) = fscanf(fid,'%f\n',1);
    c = c + 1;
end`

Answer (score 0):

`*scanf()` uses a format string like `"%d"`, not a multi-character constant like `'%d'`
Detail: `"` vs. `'`.

`"%[]` does not use a trailing `'s'` as OP used in `'%[a-zA-Z.=\t\b]s'`

`"%n"` records the `int` count of characters scanned so far.

Suggest

```
// Adjust these as needed
#define SKIPCHAR " %*[a-zA-Z.%:]"
#define EQUALFLOAT " =%f"

int n = 0;
float lat, lon, dep;
sscanf(x, SKIPCHAR EQUALFLOAT SKIPCHAR EQUALFLOAT SKIPCHAR EQUALFLOAT " %n",
   &lat, &lon, &dep, &n);

if (n > 0 && x[n] == '\0') Success();
else Fail();
```

---

To cope with different number of numbers in a line:

```
#define XN 100
float x[XN];
char *p = x;
size_t i;
for (i=0; i<XN; i++) {
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(p, SKIPCHAR " %n", &n);
  p += n;
  n = 0;
  sscanf(p, EQUALFLOAT " %n", &x[i], &n);
  if (n == 0) break;
  p += n;
}
```